# Python for loop simple array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Hi I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc--ghs-d1--asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/1215337195041/1/so_false')

products = []

div = driver.find_element_by_id('listings')

product_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="listings"]//a[@title]')
product_price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="listings"]//span[@class="price"]/span')
product_wasprice = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//strike[@class="wasprice"]')
product_weight = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class="subTitle"]')

products = [product_title, product_weight, product_wasprice, product_weight]

for item in product_title:
    print item.text.strip()

driver.close()
```

Currently it prints out all items that come up in `product_title`.

I would like to use the array that I have defined as `products` so that I can create an output csv file that has all values iterated through `products`.

so currently my output looks like:

```
product1,
product2,
etc...
```

and I would like:

```
product_title1, product_weight1, product_wasprice1, product_weight1
product_title2, product_weight2, product_wasprice2, product_weight2
```

I guess it is just knowing how to define a for loop that traverses through all the array elements.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), or its more-efficient cousin [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). These combine iterables so that you can loop through them at the same time.

```
from itertools import izip
products = izip(product_title, product_price, product_wasprice, product_weight)

for row in products:
    print ", ".join(item.text.strip() for item in row)
```

Using the above example, each `row` will be a tuple containing one element from each of the lists passed into `zip`. If you need to do further calculation with this data, you can also expand these tuples with comma-separated variables in the `for`.

```
for title, price, wasprice, weight in products:
    pass # your code here
```

Comment: May I suggest [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) in Python 2. Especially for (very) long lists.

Comment: Hi Dan thanks for the help! However I get the following output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "waheguru.py", line 18, in <module>
    print ", ".join(row)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, WebElement found

Comment: @JaspalSinghRathour Sorry; forgot the elements weren't strings. Edited answer to fix.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Yes, that's better. Added it to the answer.

Comment: HI Dan, great stuff getting closer. Now I do get a list but it seems to be missing some items from the loop. The output I get is: , £3.98, £2.08, 800g
, £2.08, £1.48, 340g 
Kellogg's Coco Pops, £2.00, £2.68, 350g
, £2.38, £3.18, 350g
, £2.00, £2.68, 550g
Kelloggs Rice Krispies, £1.98, £2.68, 295g
, £1.18, , 350g
, £1.18, , 500g
Kellogg's Coco Pops Croco Copters, £2.78, , 450g
, £2.80, , 450 but when I run the original product_title only query there are about 58 products...

Comment: @JaspalSinghRathour This is assuming all you lists have the same number of items. Is it the case?

Comment: Actually some lists do not include a was price. They all include the product, weight and price.

Comment: `izip_longest` will join the lists together and show all of the results, but this will almost certainly not do what you want either, unless the items with a "was price" are all at the top. You probably need to find the container element for each product with Selenium and loop through those instead.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I have replaced izip_longest with the two izip instances above but I get:, £3.98, £2.08, 800g
, £2.08, £1.48, 340g
Kellogg's Coco Pops, £2.00, £2.68, 350g
, £2.38, £3.18, 350g
, £2.00, £2.68, 550g
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "waheguru.py", line 19, in <module>
    print ", ".join(item.text.strip() for item in row)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' and the was prices is actually present for each element. So I guess when it doesnt exist we just want to print a line feed or empty string. Thanks for your patience with this one!

Comment: `item.text.strip()` needs to check for None now,. Consider replacing it with something like `item.text.strip() if item else ''`

Comment: Thanks Dan! Now it is printing the whole list. However the items are not in the right order eg: , £3.98, £2.08, 800g
, £2.08, £1.48, 340g
Kellogg's Coco Pops, £2.00, £2.68, 350g
, £2.38, £3.18, 350g
, £2.00, £2.68, 550g
Kelloggs Rice Krispies, £1.98, £2.68, 295g

Kellogg's Coco Pops Croco Copters, £2.78, , 450g If I print these of as single elements and then join in a speadsheet it is okay but for some reason Kellogs coco pops is after some prices when it should be the first item followed by 3.98, [no wasprice], 800g. I think we are almost there now just the order